# What is this programming "syntax" on code.org

Tags: syntax

Out of curiosity, i tried a few tutorials on [code.org](http://code.org/).

I began with this [one](http://learn.code.org/hoc/1).

Have you seen this graphical syntax using blocks ?
Is it some kind of standard ?
Or is completely home made ?

Here is what it looks like :

http://files.websitetoolbox.com/149581/1788549

Where can i learn more about it ?
I think it is really easy to read, and i wonder if i could use somewhere else, programming c# or c++, java, even javascript.

I am still not sure if business code would really be easy to read using this syntax.

Comment: http://18.7.29.232/handle/1721.1/41550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely to be some form of `OpenBlocks`, it's a way of representing your code and what it does in a more intuitive fashion, you can read more about it at the link I posted as a comment.

Notably, a similar solution was in use for [creating Android apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Inventor_for_Android) too .

Answer (score 1):

This is called blockly. You can find a lot of information from [blockly's FAQ](https://developers.google.com/blockly/about/faq). Hope that helps.